# Mocha Promise testing meteor method does not work

Tags: javascript, testing, meteor, mocha.js

I'm trying to figure it out why meteor testing with mocha does not work with async meteor methods, every time I run this error comes up:

`Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.`

I tried even with the old style mocha async testing, using done callback but it didn't work.

This is the spec:

```
import { assert, expect } from 'meteor/practicalmeteor:chai';
import { resetDatabase } from 'meteor/xolvio:cleaner';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Random } from 'meteor/random';
import { Promise } from 'meteor/promise';
import { Expenses } from './collection';

import './config';
import './methods';

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  describe('expense creation', function () {
    beforeEach(function () {
      resetDatabase();
    });

    it('should not be created if there is no budget yet', function () {
      const userId = Random.id();

      // Find the internal implementation of the task method so we can test it in isolation
      const createExpense = Meteor.server.method_handlers['createExpense'];

      // Set up a fake method invocation that looks like what the method expects
      const invocation = { userId };

      const expense = {
        description: 'test',
        amount: 100,
        created: new Date('2017-01-01'),
        type: Expenses.types.ESP.code,
        user_id: 'examplied'
      };

      const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // Run the method with `this` set to the fake invocation
        createExpense.apply(invocation, [expense], (err, res) => {
          if (err) reject(err);
          resolve(res);
        });
      });

      return promise
        .then(res => {
          expect(res).to.be.null;
        })
        .catch(err => {
          expect(err).to.not.be.null;
        });
    });
  });
}
```

I am running this tests with:

`meteor test --once --driver-package dispatch:mocha-phantomjs`

I have the following versions but I tried with the most recent ones:

```
dispatch:mocha-phantomjs@0.1.7
dispatch:phantomjs-tests@0.0.5
```

What am I missing?

Comment: are you sure the test is passing? i get that same message when the test is failing.

Comment: I think I never said that the test is passing, actually it is not. It fails every time I run the test suite.
Did you experienced this before?

Comment: A promise only return 1 value, try to change with: return promise.then(res => ...).catch(err => ...)

Comment: Agree with the comment above, the `then` handler has only 1 argument. Try to remove the latest expectation, and in case it works add a `.catch` handler.

Comment: @MarcoL Hey, I tried to do it as you said but didn't make the difference.

Comment: Does the promise take more than 2 seconds to execute? Try to put this.timeout(10000); as first line of the test and check if it passes. (Fix the then handler thing either way)

Comment: @MarcoL No, it doesn't. No matter how bigger the time out is, it always fail with the same error after the timeout.